# TFS2008 Remote Access No VPN Option

Tags: remote-access

I am new to TFS and trying to setup where remote users can access the Source Repository and Work Items without having a VPN to the local network.

Is this possible?

From what I've seen the answer is NO. The TFS Proxy component does NOT appear to be what is needed to allow remote access, but rather a way to improve speed for remote users as long as they have VPN connection.

So how can configure TFS with NO VPN requirement?

Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

The second problem is how will you authenticate them? If you can't VPN to the network, there will be lot's of issues with the Domain access to the TFS.
Home made solution is to create an machine in DMZ and open it via RDP to the remote users (it's not safe at all)

Comment: Good point. This looks like a flaw in TFS, they should provide a username/pwd option in .NET. This would then authenticate them. 

Any other possible solutions? Surely, I'm not the only one with consultants offsite that are using a onsite TFS server.